# Spring boot : issue in activiti maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, activiti

I want to use activiti in my project.I also use spring security in it. when i add activiti maven dependency to `pom.xml` all `jpa` service such as login not working. when i remove activiti dependency its work correctly.

spring boot version: 1.3.3 and activiti version is 5.17.0.

```
 <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

 <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>5.17.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>5.17.0</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
```

and my spring security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You miss things as what Spring Boot version? what activiti version? What do you mean by `not working`? Do you get any exception thrown?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker , thanks. spring boot version 1.3.3 and activiti version 5.17.0,  and not any exception throw.

Comment: Keep in mind you can edit the question yourself adding such relevant data.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, if you want more info i put in my question. thanks.

Comment: I think You do not need to add 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' dependency additional when you use 'spring-boot-starter-jpa' of org.activiti. It already contains  'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' dependency.